# How can I redirect to previous page after login in react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am looking to redirect to the page the user visited last after he/she finishes login, I am using react-router for this. How can I do that?

Answer (score 11):

You can use query strings to accomplish this.

Add dependency [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to your react app.

Whenever the user is trying to access a protected path, you have to redirect to the log-in screen if the user is not logged in yet. To do this you will do something like this.

```
history.push('/login');
```

But we can pass the previous as a query as follows. We can take the previous path using `useLocation` from `react-router`

```
const prevLocation = useLocation();
history.push(`/login?redirectTo=${prevLocation}`);
```

Now after successful login, we can get the query string that was passed in the previous path. We can set a default path if the previous path is `null`.

```
const handleSuccessLogin = () => {
      const location = useLocation();
      const { redirectTo } = queryString.parse(location.search);
      history.push(redirectTo == null ? "/apps" : redirectTo);
 };
```

This is IMO the best solution out there.

Comment: Beware of *invalidated url redirect attacks* when passing redirect urls as query params. More on that here: https://www.virtuesecurity.com/kb/url-redirection-attack-and-defense/.

Comment: The return of `useLocation()` is a Location object, not a string.
When you do `history.push(`/login?redirectTo=${prevLocation}`);` you're encoding a Location object to string. You're pushing this `/login?redirectTo=[object Object]`.

Comment: This approach does not work if the `/login` further redirects to another URL (e.g. IDP login page, which is very common in enterprise / SaaS scenarios).

Answer (score 5):

@Burhan's solution works well if `/login` is a simple login page without further redirects. In my scenario, the login page just checks the credentials in `localStorage` and further redirects to the IdP login page if credentials are unavailable or expired.

My solution using `react-router-dom@6` and `aws-amplify` for **Federated Login/SSO** is demonstrated in the following code snippets. Note they are not complete or runnable but just explain how it works.

1. In App component use `PrivateRoute` (refer to react-router-dom@6 doc for details) to check if the login credentials are available (`auth` is provided via a separate AuthContext which is out of this topic):

```
const PrivateRoute: React.FC<{user: AuthenticatedUser}> = ({ user }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
};
```

In the App component applies the `PrivateRoute` to `/`:

```
return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute user={auth.user} />}>
          ... // Other routes
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
);
```

2. In Login component before calls `aws-amplify` to start the federated login process, store the original URL into `sessionStorage`:

```
  const login = async () => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('beforeLogin', location.state?.from?.pathname);
    await Auth.federatedSignIn();
  };
```

3. In the federated login callback handler, get both the location state and url from `sessionStorage` and use whichever available after calling auth context to set the authenticated user:

```
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then((currentUser) => {
        if (currentUser) {
          auth.setUser(currentUser);
          const beforeLoginUrl = sessionStorage.getItem('beforeLogin');
          sessionStorage.removeItem('beforeLogin');
          navigate(beforeLoginUrl ?? location.state?.from ?? '/default');
        }
      })
      .catch(console.error);
```

I need to check both as in my case if Login component finds valid credentials it would not redirect to IdP at all thus `sessionStorage` would not have the URL but only `location.state?.from` has.

Answer (score 4):

I adapted @Bonttimo 's first solution to pass the entire `location` object in state, so that you can preserve eventual search queries in the original url.

**The login button:**

```js
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export const Navigation: FC = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <Link to="/accounts/login" state={{ redirectTo: location }}>
      <Button text="Login" />
    </Link>
  )
}
```

The same if you're using protected routes that redirect to the login page (based on [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-private-routes/)):

```js
import React, { FC, useContext } from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserContext } from "../contexts/user.context";

type Props = {
  redirectPath?: string;
};

export const ProtectedRoute: FC<Props> = ({ redirectPath = "/accounts/login" }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { currentUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  if (!currentUser) {
    return <Navigate to={redirectPath} replace state={{ redirectTo: location }} />;
  }

  return <Outlet />;
};
```

Then the Login page:

```js
type RedirectLocationState = {
  redirectTo: Location;
};

export const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { state: locationState } = useLocation();

  const onLogin = () => {
    if (locationState) {
      // state is any by default
      const { redirectTo } = locationState as RedirectLocationState;
      navigate(`${redirectTo.pathname}${redirectTo.search}`);
    }
  }

  return (...)
}
```

This allows you to preserve the original url intact.

E.g. someone sent you a link to `/users/list?country=13`, but only authenticated users can see the users list page. This solution would redirect you to the login page and, upon logging in, it would take you back to `/users/list?country=13`.

Comment: It is awesome if implemented, I like this solution

Answer (score 2):

There are two easy ways of doing this in React router v6, passing the previous location in the link state or just with the useNavigate hook.

**First solution (Passing the previous location in the link state)**

```
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
      <NavLink to="/login" state={{ prev: location.pathname }}>
        Login
      </NavLink>
  );
}
```

then in the **login component** extracting the state

```
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Login() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { state } = useLocation();
    
    // Then when the user logs in you redirect them back with
    const onLogin = () => navigate(state);
    return (...)
};
```

**Second solution (Using only the useNavigate hook)**

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Login() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // Then when the user logs in you redirect them back with the -1
    // means go one page back in the history. you can also pass -2...
    const onLogin = () => navigate(-1);
    return (...)
};
```

Comment: The second solution is very error-prone, because you're assuming that the page you want to go back to is always the page immediately before the login page in the stack, which might not always be the case. As for the first solution, I would pass the entire `location` object (not just `location.pathname`) in state in case you want to preserve possible search queries in the original url.

Answer (score -1):

To redirect to the previous page after login in React Router, you can achieve this by storing the previous page URL in the state or in local storage before redirecting the user to the login page. Then, after successful login, you can redirect the user back to the stored previous page URL.

Here's a step-by-step approach to implement this:

1. **Store Previous Page URL**: Before redirecting the user to the login page, store the current page URL in the state or local storage.
2. **Redirect to Login Page**: Redirect the user to the login page.
3. **Handle Login**: After successful login, retrieve the stored previous page URL from the state or local storage.
4. **Redirect to Previous Page**: Redirect the user to the previous page URL.

Here's an example implementation using React Router and local storage:

```
// Import necessary modules
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

// Function to get previous page URL from local storage
const getPreviousPageUrl = () => {
  return localStorage.getItem('previousPageUrl');
};

// Function to set previous page URL in local storage
const setPreviousPageUrl = (url) => {
  localStorage.setItem('previousPageUrl', url);
};

// Component for login page
const LoginPage = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  // Store previous page URL before redirecting to login page
  useEffect(() => {
    setPreviousPageUrl(location.pathname);
  }, []);

  // Function to handle login
  const handleLogin = () => {
    // Perform login authentication
    // If login successful, redirect to previous page
    // Replace this with your actual login logic
    // For demonstration, redirect to previous page after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      const previousPageUrl = getPreviousPageUrl();
      history.push(previousPageUrl || '/');
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Login Page</h2>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

In this example:

- The `LoginPage` component stores the previous page URL in local storage using `setPreviousPageUrl` function before redirecting to the login page.
- After successful login, it retrieves the previous page URL from local storage using `getPreviousPageUrl` function and redirects the user back to the previous page.
- Make sure to clear the stored previous page URL from local storage once the redirect is performed to avoid redirection to the same page again in subsequent logins.

Remember to adjust this code according to your specific routing setup and authentication logic.

Comment: This doesn't achieve what is being asked. Your solution redirects always to the same page.